# Any information about this SMD component? FAH45 MK

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I have this SMD component with some markings, but I am having difficulties finding information about it. I hope someone could share some information.

[image: picture attached]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairchild SMBJ30(C)A TVS in SMB capsule.

https://datasheet.octopart.com/SMBJ36A.-Fairchild-datasheet-8213257.pdf

[image]